# Magento reorder with existing order price

Tags: magento-enterprise, price, programmatically, reorder

I have a requirement where an order needs to be created from an existing order i.e Re-order feature of magento but programatically. A cron job dispatches a reorder event based on certain conditions. The below code looks up the order-id and creates a new order successfully. However, the new order picks the updated price of the product whereas I need it to be the same as the previous order. How can I modify it to set pricing from the last order?

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($lastOrderId);
$order_model = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
try {
    $order->setReordered(true);
    $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getInfoInstance();

    $order_model->getSession()->setUseOldShippingMethod(true);            
    $reorder = $order_model->initFromOrder($order);
    $newOrder = $reorder->createOrder();
    $newOrderId = $newOrder->getIncrementId();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log('Renewal for Profile #'.$profileId.': '.$e, null, 'prosub-debug.log');
    Mage::logException($e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should iterate all items of both orders and adjust the prices of each one. (take in account the row_total and the discounts applied to the original order)

If you want to display the difference you can leave the `price` and apply a discount, otherwise just copy all price related fields:

- price
- base_price
- original_price
- base_original_price

This should be enough.